# Flash OCX Error crashes IE6/7

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, crash, ocx

Has anyone encountered this error before? I am trying to debug an issue for a client and can not seem to get anywhere with this.

With a clear Internet cache I visit http://www.safcoproducts.com and almost every time (on first load) it crashes IE 6 and 7.   This does not occur in FireFox.  We have tested the same files on a different server and this error cannot be replicated as well.

Without a clear cache the error seems to come and go when it pleases.

There is a streaming music player and well as a progressive download video "theater".

Can anyone shed some insight?

Answer (score 1):

The error will only occur in IE cause ocx means ActiveX. I would recommend embedding the your Flash object using [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)